# Writing output of an application as a sound file

Tags: c, bash, freebsd

I am using espeak on BSD to output text as sound. My problem is that I want it to take it as a .mp3 but I am having little luck. I tried piping the output to tee but I guess that only works with stdout not just playing a sound.

Any ideas? My last resort would be recompiling my own version of espeak that allows me to save to a file instead of playing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write it as wave and then convert it with `ffmpeg`:

```
espeak "HelloWorld" -w <file>.wav
```

Or pipe to `ffmpeg`

```
espeak "HelloWorld" --stdout | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 output.mp3
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/commands.html):

> -w < wave file>
>   Writes the speech output to a file in WAV format, rather than speaking it.
>
> --stdout
>   Writes the speech output to stdout as it is produced, rather than speaking it. The data starts with a WAV file header which indicates the sample rate and format of the data. The length field is set to zero because the length of the data is unknown when the header is produced.

It looks like both of those options produce WAV files, but you can easily convert those without another program like ffmpeg.